# How can I factorize 2 differents ComboBox with the same code?

Tags: c#, .net

Something is annoying me but I don't know how to solve it. Here is the code :

```
    public static void FillComboBox(ComboBox cb, DataTable dt)
    {
        cb.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cb.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void FillComboBoxColumn(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col, DataTable dt)
    {
        col.Items.Clear();
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            col.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is the same code but with 2 differents objects as ComboBox. I can't see how to factorize it and it may be very simple. Can you give me an edge ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void FillCollection(IList collection, DataTable dt)
{
    collection.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        collection.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
}

public static void FillComboBox(ComboBox cb, DataTable dt)
{
    FillCollection( cb.Items, dt );
}

public static void FillComboBoxColumn(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col, DataTable dt)
{
    FillCollection( col.Items, dt );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the ComboBox and DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for your own implementation. Posted but liked Sir Rufo's answer better. But if you want to add more custom code this is a way to do it.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt; // values here
        MyComboBox cb = new MyComboBox();
        cb.InitItems(dt);

        MyDataGridViewComboBoxColumn gvcb = new MyDataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cb.InitItems(dt);
    }
}

public class MyComboBox : ComboBox, Itest
{
    // apply Sir Rufo answer here
    public void InitItems(DataTable table)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Items.Add(row);
        }
    }
}

public class MyDataGridViewComboBoxColumn: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, Itest
{
    // apply Sir Rufo answer here
    public void InitItems(DataTable table)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Items.Add(row);
        }
    }
}

public interface Itest
{
    void InitItems(DataTable table);
}
```

Comment: But that is also duplicated code as in the question. OP is looking for a DRY solution